# OpenLayers 3 get current center

Tags: openlayers

Is it possible to get the current position (lat/lng/zoom) in OpenLayers 3 (Like `map.getCenter()` in Leaflet)? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just type:

```
map.getView().getCenter()
```

You should look at [official examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/) source code: they will really help you.